# Where do I save selector color on android

Tags: android, android-layout, selector, android-resources

Here is my selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

apparently I cannot save it in the `/drawable` folder as my android won't compile. Then if I create a `/color` folder in `res` I get a red mark from eclipse. So where do I save my selector so I can use it as the background color of a TextView (or really any other view).

I have a `colors.xml` file in values, but how would I add a selector to it?

**THE ACTUAL SOLUTION**

I am posting this edit in case someone else needs help. I hope you this saves you some time.

For the correct answer, I did following

In `strings.xml`

```
<drawable name="black_drawable">@color/black</drawable>
<drawable name="white_drawable">@color/white</drawable>
```

In `colors.xml`

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

Then in the selector, I did

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_drawable" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_drawable"/>

</selector>
```

The selector is saved in `/drawable` as `selector_black_white.xml`

Comment: You should create _color.xml_ inside _values_ not in **res**

Comment: sorry about the typos, I change the colors but error persists

Comment: could you post _color.xml_ ? maybe the name with numbers it's not allowed

Comment: Your setup is correct; `<selector>` goes in `res/drawable`, and colors goes in `res/values/colors.xml`. Your `<selector>` looks good, so post your `colors.xml`. The names of your colors shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Why would you store a `drawable` in `strings.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last edit i messed up pretty in my previous edit sorry my bad this one is working now
res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/whiteColor"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/backColor"/>

</selector>
```

then on your res/value/string or create new values color

```
<color name="whiteColor">#000000</color>



 <color name="backColor">#ffffff</color>
```

Comment: that was not the problem. Still same issue. I edited my post with more details.

Comment: I see what you mean see my last edit and in the first code i changed your android:color to android:drawble it should work. try it and let me know pls

Comment: and selector should be inside res/drawable

Comment: i did a spelling mistake inside <color name="BbackColor">#ffffff</color> just remove "B"

Comment: Your code was a bit messy, but I used what you had before this last edit to solve my problem :) . I will show my solution in my OP in case someone else needs help.

Comment: Yeah i know im sorry for the confusion, that what happen when you try to do many think at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I found.

You just need to create a "color" folder in your res and save the file in the newly created folder.

After completing this step you will be able to get the color selector file in your attribute of respective xml file.

I'm attaching screenshots for better understanding.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsZhf.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuKik.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not the location - it should be in the /res/color folder.  The problem is in how you specify the color:

```
  <item android:color="@color/ffffff"/>
```

should be

```
   <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: that was not the problem. Still same issue. I edited my post with more details.